# Validation not working if TextField has Select attribute in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created two fields (Input/Select) box, based on values availability (empty/non empty) I'm changing the outline color.
These validation working on Input box but fails on select box.

```
const ValidationTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& input:valid + fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
    '& input:invalid + fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
    '& input:valid:focus + fieldset': {
      borderLeftWidth: 6,
      padding: '4px !important', // override inline-style
    },
  },
})(TextField);


<ValidationTextField
          id="validation-outlined-input"
          label={field.labelName}
          placeholder={field.labelName}
          inputProps={inputProps}
          required
          variant="outlined"
        />

 <ValidationTextField
          id="validation-outlined-input"
          select
          required
          label={field.labelName}
          variant="outlined"
        >
          {field.options.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </ValidationTextField>
```

Comment: can you create a codesandbox, it will be helpfult to figure out the issue?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-twzk2